# Why is gitignore ignoring all my files despite writing only one file to be ignored?

Tags: git, gitignore

I created a gitignore in the root of my project folder like this:

```
*

!src/
!.gitignore
```

And in my src folder, I have 2 files and a file I want to keep in the local folder but exclude from the repository (3 files in total). So I created another gitignore file in the src folder like this:

```
file.txt
```

The command line:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

When I went to my repo, it indeed excluded everything but the src folder and the gitignore file, but in the src folder in the repo, I found only the gitignore file and not the other files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your top-level `.gitignore` file has the rule:

```
*
```

This matches *all files in all folders at all times*.  So any file anywhere is ignored, unless otherwise specified.

To fix this, use the "anchor" concept: tell Git that `*` in the top level should *only apply at the top level*, i.e.:

```
/*
```

Now only *top-level* files are ignored (and any folders are not searched either, unless overridden, e.g., as by your `!src/` line).

(Note that the:

```
!.gitignore
```

rule in the top level file means that all `.gitignore` files everywhere are not-ignored, unless overridden by a more-local rule, but that's probably what you want anyway.  Still, you could anchor that rule too, if you wanted.)

Comment: Run (on the command line, not in the IDE) `git check-ignore -v src/file.txt` to see which `.gitignore` rule is making `git add .` skip `src/file.txt`.